# why is there a bunch of white space on the right of my page?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

There is a bunch of white space to the right of my page and I can't figure out how to get rid of it.
I am pretty new to coding.
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>blablabla</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
        <div class="topheader">
            <img src="uglyperson.jpg" id="logo"/>
            <h1 id="quote"><em>"blablablablabla."</em></h1>
            <p>
            <a href="#">bla</a> 
            <a href="#">bla</a> 
            <a href="#">bla</a> 
            <a href="#">bla</a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <!-- END HEADER -->
        <hr />
    </div>  

</body>

</html>
```

And my CSS:

```
a:link {
    color:white;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:50px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

a:visited {
    color:white;
    background-color:lightgreen;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:50px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

p {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:750px;
    min-width:100%;
}

#logo {
    height:150px;
}

h1 {
    font-size:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:180px;
}

.wrap {
    width:95%;
    min-width:100%;
}
```

I have no idea what's wrong, I checked my code, and everything seems to be fine, at least as far as I know.

Comment: Try inspecting the elements on your page. Is any of them causing the whitespace to the right?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `html` and `body` width?  I would look into including a reset style sheet before your custom css file

Comment: Pasted your code into a fiddle, though obviously without the left image: http://jsfiddle.net/joadarr6/

What exactly do you mean by whitespace on the right? Do you mean the spaces separating the bla bla blas? Or the empty space to the right of that whole section?

Comment: I already checked, I can't seem to find anything, that's why I'm asking. Sorry.

Comment: @rmehlinger to the right of the whole section

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you set the `min-width: 100%` on the `<p>` tag. It is causing it to be as wide as the screen, but missplaced to the left because of the `left:750px;`.

Instead, remove the `min-width`. If the point was to keep the bla bla bla inline, use `white-space: nowrap` instead:

[**See DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5v96Lmhv/)

```
p {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:750px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
body {
  margin 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

to your CSS.